# Application of Catalan number

Tags: catalan-numbers, applications

Hi guys just a quick questions
What are the real life application of catalan numbers?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: They are useful when you go shopping in Catalonia. I voted to close.

Comment: I voted to close, but am now about to give an answer. I don't know how to retract a close vote...

Comment: The faq explains how such questions are not appropriate for mathoverflow. There are other fora where you will have better luck.

Comment: Sorry I admit forgetting to check the FAQ
I'll be sure to check it next time then
Thanks for the help anw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In all seriousness, this type of enumerative combinatorics is very useful e.g. in figuring out expected running time for computer programs.  An example involving Catalan numbers (which may seem a little contrived, but I think things like this probably do really come up) is: count how many times you go through the inner loop, i.e. how many times you print "hello world", in:

for $i_1=0$ to $1$

for $i_2=i_1$ to $2$

for $i_3=i_2$ to $3$

...

for $i_n = i_{n-1}$ to $n$

print "hello world"

Comment: You're welcome.  I wonder about these things too.

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed at great length in:

"Catalan numbers with applications" by Thomas Koshy. The main application seems to be to make money for the publisher (the book is insanely expensive), but google books has extracts.